# How to make a material that toggles between 2 colors when object surface overlapping?

Tags: materials

I want to make a material that toggles between 2 colors when overlapping.

For example: if the object surface overlaps an odd number from the camera ray, the material will show yellow. If the object surfaces overlap an even number from the camera ray, the material will show cyan. If it's not possible, using a compositor is fine too.

[image: image example]

This is a video example I want to achieve. (3:20 - 3:33)
https://youtu.be/zkLJoFp2UAE?t=200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your example will have been done in compositing.. that leaves much more room for flexibility; you can shoot your basic plates, and then decide how to combine them at a later stage.

But if your shapes are single surfaces, and you don't mind using OSL, which means you can't use your GPU,then this could be enough for a variety of effects:

```
shader LayersBehind( 

 // Number of layers found behind P    
 output int LayersBehind = 0
)
{  
    point ray0 = P;     //The first of a sequence of ray origins
    int limit = 20;     //Limit on length of ray-chain
    
    while ((LayersBehind<limit) && trace(ray0,-I,"mindist",0.000001)){
        getmessage("trace", "P", ray0);
        LayersBehind++;   
    }   
}
```

The output of this script-node is the number of surfaces hit, behind the shading-point, on the way out from the camera.

[image]

I guess the computation for this kind of render isn't too high, so sacrificing your GPU may not be too much of a hit.

[image]